# Python 3.6//Django 2.1.4//templates: for loop not working on users

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

i am trying to display all users in my db onto html with a for loop but it returns nothing:

here's my home view in views.py :

```
def home(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render( request, 'home.html', { 'users': users } )
```

here's my home.html template:

```
{% extends 'base_test.html' %} 


{% block content %}

{{user.username}} <!-- returns user1 because he is logged in -->

{% for user in users %} <!-- not working -->
  <p>{{user.username}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

User.objects.all() from from `python3 manage.py shell` returns :

```
<QuerySet [<User: user1>, <User: user2>]>
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

i have tried a class based view and it worked.
 with a list view
**views.py**

```
from django.generic.views import ListView
class Home(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

**urls.py** (class based views are called this way)

```
urlspatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base_test.html' %} 
{% block content %}

<!-- i read that the class based view automatically creates variables in the shade for you to use. -->
{% for user in user_list %}

     <!-- added another variable to check if it is effective -->  
    <p>{{user.username}}: {{user.email}}</p> 

{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and the for loop to iterate through users worked perfectly.
Don't hesitate to propose a better solution.